# Connect Adobe Flex To Arcgis Service?

Tags: web-services, windows-xp, flash-builder, arcgis-server

I'm trying to connect my flex app to my Arcgis webservices. I tried using the connect to webservice interface. But I keep getting this error.

> There was an error during service
>   introspection. WSDLException:
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem
>   parsing
>   'http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/geodata/MapServer'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   element type "link" must be terminated
>   by the matching end-tag "/link".

My web service looks like this

> ArcGIS Services Directory Home >
>   geodata (MapServer)   Help | API
>   Reference geodata (MapServer) View In:
>   ArcMap   ArcGIS Explorer   ArcGIS
>   JavaScript   Google Earth   ArcGIS.com
>   Map
>
> View Footprint In:   Google Earth
>
> Service Description:
>
> Map Name: Layers
>
> Legend
>
> All Layers and Tables
>
> Layers:
>
> ```
> Geocoding_Result layer (0)
> ```
>
> Tables:
>
> Description:
>
> Copyright Text:
>
> Spatial Reference: 4326
>
> Single Fused Map Cache: false
>
> Intial Extent:
>
> ```
> XMin: -95.901360470612
> YMin: 29.4513469530748
> XMax: -95.1472749640384
> YMax: 30.045474927951
> Spatial Reference: 4326
> ```
>
> Full Extent:
>
> ```
> XMin: -100.3273442
> YMin: 29.451583
> XMax: -94.8230278
> YMax: 31.250677
> Spatial Reference: 4326
> ```
>
> Units: esriDecimalDegrees
>
> Supported Image Format Types:
>   PNG24,PNG,JPG,DIB,TIFF,EMF,PS,PDF,GIF,SVG,SVGZ,AI,BMP
>
> Document Info:
>
> ```
> Title:
> Author:
> Comments:
> Subject:
> Category:
> Keywords:
> Credits:
> ```
>
> Supported Interfaces:   REST   SOAP
>
> Supported Operations:   Export Map
>   Identify   Find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you already know... but if you are trying to connect to an ArcGIS Server using Flex you might be interested in the ArcGIS API for Flex - http://links.esri.com/flex - it will take care of most of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Antarr,

It's a little hard to tell from your question what exactly you are trying to do.  But here are a couple possibilities:

1) It looks like you might be trying to add a reference to this service via Flash Builder's "Connect to Web Service" dialog, which you would use for a SOAP web service, but not for the REST endpoint you note above (http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/geodata/MapServer). If you are intending to use the REST endpoints, then you need to use the appropriate ESRI ArcGIS API for Flex class (for example DynamicMapServiceLayer or Locator) for whatever you are trying to do (generate a map image, geocode addresses, etc).  Look at the ESRI help on the Flex API for more information:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/index.html

2) If you are intending to use the ESRI SOAP API then you do want to use Flash Builder's "Connect to Web Service" dialog, but then you must use the SOAP service endpoint, which would be something like: http://localhost/ArcGIS/services/geodata//MapServer?wsdl (though I don't know why you'd want to do this since the Flex API is really designed to be used with ESRI's REST service endpoints).

3) The only layer in your service is called "Geocoding_Result" - is that an actual feature layer or just a temporary output from a geocoding operation done with ArcMap? I am not sure whether a temporary result would work when published as a service.

See if any of these suggestions help.  If not, then clarify what you are trying to do and perhaps I can give you more specific assistance.